# Joomla 4 - Category blog view - hide content of article

Tags: joomla-4.x, category-blog

Am I missing something here? Using Joomla 4 and Cassiopeia template.

On the category blog view, I just want to output the article image and title. But underneath that is the WHOLE article text.

Is there a setting to disable this? I dont want any of the article contents on the catgory blog page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Article place a Read More link as the first line of the Article, essentially providing an empty Introduction text area and thus nothing will be displayed.

You may also have to tweak your Menu and or Article setting to also hide the Read More button if you don't want that to be displayed in your layout.

[image]